# Match data in table with only one cell with the "key" info

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Table format in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UC7eE.png)

Hi there!

I'm trying to write a formula that will count the data entries in the tables as formatted in the provided picture. Note, the "count" cell is not the count I'm aiming for, but a count that is provided from the report I'm needing to work with.

Each row of data is a different type and status. I need to count each type and each status relative to the name in the first cell. This needs to be as autonomous as possible as the end result will be used by much less technical employees.

My initial thought was just to write a macro that fills in the name on every row, but I'd like to avoid macros as much as possible. Doing everything with formulas would be the best solution.

I know that once I can link the name to the data, COUNTIFS should do what I need. I'm hoping there's a simple solution here.

I've tried manually entering the names in each row, but that's time consuming as the report can vary from only a few lines to thousands, depending on the week. I started writing a macro that would just take care of this, but I really need to avoid macros if at all possible (not my choice, limitations of the workplace).

What I've done for the other data I have that comes formatted better is a COUNTIFS statement like so:

`=COUNTIF(reportArrayWhereNamesAre,employeeName,reportArrayWhereJobTypeIs,specificJobType)`

This results in a table with job names, and the amount of work assigned in each type per week. Now I need to do the same for work status (closed, open, pending, et cetera) but the status report is provided in a different format.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Edit:

| name1 | 5 |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | status1 | type1 |  |
|  |  | status1 | type2 |  |
|  |  | status2 | type2 |  |
|  |  | status3 | type3 |  |
|  |  | status3 | type4 |  |
| name2 | 2 |  |  |  |
|  |  | status1 | type4 |  |
|  |  | status1 | type3 |  |
| name3 | 6 |  |  |  |
|  |  | status2 | type2 |  |
|  |  | status1 | type3 |  |
|  |  | status1 | type4 |  |
|  |  | status2 | type2 |  |
|  |  | status3 | type3 |  |
|  |  | status3 | type4 |  |

Comment: Sorry to hear that you want to avoid VBA. I used to deal with reports like this all the time out of Sage 50, so I just wrote a very simple macro to iterate through the rows and fill down for any blank cells in the first two columns.

Comment: If you ask a question and you want us to help you, please post some (copyable) sample data and the expected result with that data (you could use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables ).

I helps us help you.

Comment: @P.b It doesn't seem like StackOverflow's editor allows pasting of tables into the body, but there is an image of the data at the top of the post.

Comment: @P.b I completely missed your link somehow - table added.

Comment: OK, you provided step one: Data. But with this data, what do you expect us to get as a result?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the paragraph #2, I can propose you the next solution:

1. Insert a row above #1.
2. Title each column (Name, Count, Type, Status).
3. Select A1 and apply autofilter.
4. Using autofilter, apply a filter to the column A to display blank cells.
5. Select all displayed (empty) cells in the column A, starting from A3. A3 should be the active cell. Type "=A2" and press Ctrl+Enter. It fills the column A with appropriate names.
6. Insert two pivot tables as depicted below. They report "count each type and each status relative to the name in the first cell".

[image]

The variant with formulas is possible, but it's very dependent from a required report view.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This solution ended up not working for me, so far. For some reason, "Ctrl+Enter" doesn't do anything for the data provided. Not sure why. I tried searching around the web and wasn't able to come up with a solution for that, either.

Comment: 'Ctrl+Enter' enters the formula into all selected cells. Pls. try it on any empty range: select few cells, type a simple formula (e. g. "=2") and press 'Ctrl+Enter'. All selected cells should get this formula. Look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNZj6AbbCBU